# Symfony2: InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "templating.helpers.assets" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

While working on my Symfony2 project, I (seemingly) randomly got the error `InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "templating.helpers.assets" does not exist.` when going to any page. I have tried going back to earlier commits, but that doesn't change anything. So it doesn't seem to be any of my own source code. I also cannot `composer update`. I have tried removing the cache, vendor directory, and composer.lock file, but I still get this error:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Generating autoload files
>
> Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
>
> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
>   The service definition "templating.helpers.assets" does not exist.
>
> Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception
>
> [RuntimeException]
>   An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like a typo. Shouldn't it be: `templating.helper.assets` (no s). Is any of your dependencies trying to use that? Have you tried searching your project for that string? Was any of your composer packages recently updated? Do you use fixed versions?

Comment: I don't use fixed versions, but I had not updated packages any time around when the problem happened. I did try searching for the string in my project, but nothing very helpful (at least to me) came up. Just stuff like TwigBundle Assets Extension and some cache stuff before I cleared the cache. But I wasn't editing any twig files, just scss at the time. Now that you bring up it being plural, I was organizing my scss files and created a subfolder in the css folder called `helpers`. But I even tried removing that folder, and the error was still happening.

Comment: Luckily I had deployed the code to a remote dev server before the problem happened, so I was able to just grab that and update to the latest commit, which has "fixed" my problem. I still don't see what would have caused this issue though.

Comment: That's strange. Did you try to diff the two projects against each other?

Comment: I had this error today when I defined a service and made the class files. Then I changed the way I was doing something and got rid of the clas file but forgot to remove the service definition.

Comment: Have you defined any service in your own bundles which uses `templating.helper.assets`? If yes, show us the service definitions.

Comment: The `composer update` is successful, the `post-update-cmd` is failing because something registered with your DI container is referencing `templating.helpers.assets` and that service is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

FYI service `templating.helper.assets` exist

```php
php app/console container:debug  templating.helper.assets 
[container] Information for service templating.helper.assets
Service Id       templating.helper.assets
Class            Symfony\Component\Templating\Helper\CoreAssetsHelper
Tags
    - templating.helper              (alias: assets)
Scope            request
Public           yes
Synthetic        no
Lazy             no
Synchronized     no
Abstract         no
```

It is created by `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle()`
and defined in `Resources\config\templating_php.xml`

```xml
    <service id="templating.helper.assets" class="%templating.helper.assets.class%">
        <tag name="templating.helper" alias="assets" />
        <argument /> <!-- default package -->
        <argument type="collection" /> <!-- named packages -->
    </service>
```

So add this bundle in your `appKernel.php`

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        //Standard
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        //others bundles
```